# Sencha Touch built app doesn't load JSON data

Tags: ajax, extjs, build, proxy, sencha-touch-2.1

I have the following question. I'm using `sencha app build testing` to create a build of app for testing. I have some local json mock files with data to be loaded in app. Without build everything's loading fine, no problems detected. **In built version I see no ajax requests to reach these files even.**

What could happen with build to generate such a behaviour?

**Model**:

```
Ext.define('MS.model.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'desc', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'image', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'href', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'group', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'isNew', type: 'auto'}
        ]
    }
});
```

**Store**:

```
Ext.define('MS.store.Categories', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MS.model.Category',
    ],
    model: 'MS.model.Category',

    sorters: 'id',
    grouper: function (record) {
        return record.get('group');
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'categories.json',
        reader: 'json'
    },
    autoLoad: true,

    xtype: 'categoriesstore'
});
```

Comment: same issue for me, managed? please share your solution